# Why the customized docker container cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375?

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

For CI/CD purposes, I need [docker in docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated):

```
docker network create some-network
docker volume create some-docker-certs-ca
docker volume create some-docker-certs-client
docker run --privileged --name some-dind -d --network some-network --network-alias docker -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs -v some-docker-certs-ca:/certs/ca -v some-docker-certs-client:/certs/client docker:dind
```

Now if I run the docker:latest image with `-it` option, I can use docker in the container as expected:

```
docker run --rm -it --network some-network -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs -v some-docker-certs-client:/certs/client:ro docker:latest sh

/ # docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
/ #
```

But I need to customize docker:latest image in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker:latest 

# install package1
# install package2
# install package3
  ...
# install package4
```

And build the customized docker image:

```
docker build -t customized-docker .
```

But when I run the customized-docker image with `-it` options, It cannot connect to docker daemon:

```
docker run --rm -it --network some-network -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs -v some-docker-certs-client:/certs/client:ro customized-docker:latest sh

/ # docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
/ #
```

What is the problem? Isn't there any way I can use customized docker image?

***Edit:***
I found a better way to do my CI/CD without "docker in docker". As David Maze mentioned, most of the times, there is no need to use "docker in docker". But my question still remains: Why can the docker:latest container connect to docker daemon but a customized docker container cannot.

Comment: `docker:latest` and `docker:dind` are different.  But [using DinD for your CI system is generally discouraged](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/); standard practice is to share the host's Docker socket instead.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks! I know they are different! But you are right. I found a better way without using "docker in docker".

Comment: ...are you trying to use the customized image to be the containerized Docker daemon, or just for a `docker` command-line client calling the other DinD container?  I think I might have been confused reading how you were trying to use the custom image.

Comment: Does your custom image reset `ENTRYPOINT`?  Or `USER`?  The standard image has [an entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/a7534626601bce99a23f0496a3f659616522ed22/20.10/docker-entrypoint.sh) that tries to figure out what it's talking to; that you're seeing the error for the unencrypted port 2375 suggests it's not finding your certificates.

Comment: @DavidMaze Actually I don't change any of them. I just install some packages.